# Navigation in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, navigation-drawer, hamburger-menu

I have a `Navigation Drawer` which has 5 items.
If user selects an Item, I'm loading respective `Fragment` in `FrameLayout`
Now, if user pulls out the `Navigation Drawer` and selects the same Item as previous, I should not load the same `Fragment` again, so I'm saving the selected position and if previous selected position equals current selection I'm just closing the `Navigation Drawer` as follows:

```
    String title = null;
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
    android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = null;
    if (position == getPrevSelectedItem()) {
        // Already selected fragment is being displayed
    } else {
        switch (position) {
            case Numerics.ZERO:
                fragment = new DashBoardFragment();
                title = fragment.getClass().getSimpleName();
                break;
            case Numerics.ONE:
                break;
            case Numerics.TWO:
                break;
            case Numerics.THREE:
                break;
            case Numerics.FOUR:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        if (fragment != null) {
            showFragment(fragment, title);
        }
        setSelectedItem(position);
    }
```

I'm adding fragments by adding to `backstack` in order to provide back navigation to previous fragment as follows :

```
    if (fragment != null) {
        String backStateName = fragment.getClass().getName();
        mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.dashboard_container, fragment);
        mFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(backStateName);
        mFragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

**The problem is:**
            If I select Item no:3 and then select Item:4, if I navigate back the previous selection is still 4, but I'm displaying `Fragment` with no:3. So, if I select Item no:3 again from `Navigation Drawer` the `Fragment` loads again. How to solve this ??

EDIT:

```
public int getPrevSelectedItem() {
    return selectedItem;
}

public void setSelectedItem(int selectedItem) {
    this.selectedItem = selectedItem;
}
```

Comment: The `drawer` does not get `updated` when you press `back` - so you need to add some code to `onBackPressed()` in the `activity` where you update the position according to the popped `BackstackEntry`.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Fragment currentFragment = getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.dashboard_container);
if(currentFragment instanceof YouFragmentName)
    return
```

Comment: this is a better idea, but I think I'm missing a small logic in my implementation. adding it would be a better one if I fail to find my mistake. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

you can check the instance of loaded fragment on clicking the menu

```
Fragment loadedFragment= getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentLoadingSpace);

  if( !(loadedFragment instanceof  FragmentName1)){

// load fragment

        }
```

Comment: this is a better idea, but I think I'm missing a small logic in my implementation. adding it would be a better one if I fail to find my mistake. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need of `else` statement or you can use `else` only for closing `drawer`

```
public int prevPosition=-1;    

if (getPrevSelectedItem() != prevPosition) {
        // Already selected fragment is being displayed
        prevPosition =getPrevSelectedItem();  
        callFragment(position);
 } 
private void callFragment(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (position) {
    case Numerics.ZERO:
        fragment = new DashBoardFragment();
        title = fragment.getClass().getSimpleName();
        break;
    case Numerics.ONE:
        break;
    case Numerics.TWO:
        break;
    case Numerics.THREE:
        break;
    case Numerics.FOUR:
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    if (fragment != null) {
        showFragment(fragment, title);
    }
    setSelectedItem(position);

}
```

Comment: If I select 2 next I select 3. If I press back still the `getPrevSelectedItem()` gives me 3, but current position will be 2. So you code will load the Item no:2 `fragment` again

Comment: post `getPrevSelectedItem`

Comment: so you are just telling me to add one more variable to save one item back to previous `fragment`. what happens in case of more than 2 ??

Comment: have you implementd modified code? your `getPrevSelectedItem` will give you selected position not previous

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97955/discussion-between-logic-and-kishore-jethava).

Answer (score -1):

From my comment:

> The `drawer` does not get updated when you press `back` - so you need to add some code to `onBackPressed()` in the `activity`, where you update the `position` according to the popped `BackstackEntry`.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){

    String backStackEntryName = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(backCount - 2).getName(); 
     int id =  R.id.my_main_frag; //default option
     if (MyMainFrag.class.getName().equals(backStackEntryName)){
         id =  R.id.my_main_frag;
         selectedItem = 0;
     } else if (MySecondFrag.class.getName().equals(backStackEntryName)){
         id = R.id.my_second_frag;
         selectedItem = 1;
     }
      ...

     navigation.setCheckedItem(id);
     super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: I would appreciate a comment if I am getting downvoted, so I can improve my answer or see my mistakes.